# Google sheets API 4: How to append to the end of the row

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

Able to update the row by providing the range, here is the code:

```
$range = "A1:B1";
$valueRange= new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["a", "b"]]); 
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

Considering I don't know the range, how can I insert the row to the end of the sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)?  The guide for example usage is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values#appending_values).

The reference docs for `append` describe it as: `Appends values to a spreadsheet. The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values will be appended to the next row of the table, starting with the first column of the table. See the guide and sample code for specific details of how tables are detected and data is appended.`

If that's not what you're looking for, can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: I have tried append but it is not under Sheets_ValueRange and due to the lack of documentation for PHP I am unable to find the correct class to use. I am trying to find the correct class and syntax to use append in PHP SDK provided by Google.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392194/google-sheets-api-4-how-to-append-to-the-end-of-the-row-with-php - the PHP client libraries are missing the update that added the append method.  I'm working to update them and will ping that SO thread when they're updated.

Comment: Updated and It's working! If the Date is not set exclusively and using the system date, it is throwing a fatal error or that is how it is designed. Solved it by setting the date.

Answer (score 4):

As Sam pointed out, the documentation states "range is used to search for existing data" and "Values will be appended to the next row".

Therefore, if you set the Range to the entire spreadsheet, you would get the results you desire. *(Original post title says append to end of row, while your description says add a row to the end of the spreadsheet, so I assume the latter is what you want.)*

Thus, set the range to the worksheet name.

```
$range = "Sheet1";       //your worksheet name
$valueRange= new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["a", "b"]]); 
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

Row will be added to the bottom of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Probably just worth adding here that if you are adding non text base cell content, e.g. hyperlinks or formula, you might want to use   $conf = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"] as otherwise it will simply insert the value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've done a project which is quite similar to the concept of what you're doing (I used JS though), I suggest checking the rows if it's empty or not using the [GET request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) for Sheetsv4. Make it such that if the cell is empty, you'll write the appended data there using the [Write on Sheets using PUT](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing) guide. This was my dynamic workaround when I didn't know the last row.