# Google sheets API 4: How to append to the end of the row with PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am able to update a row by providing the range using the [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) method, with the following the code:

```
$range = "A1:B1";
$valueRange= new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["a", "b"]]); 
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

When using the [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method, with the following code:

```
$range = "A1:B";
$valueRange= new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["a", "b"]]); 
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
$ins = ["insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf, $ins);
```

I get the following error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
> Google_Service_Sheets_Resource_SpreadsheetsValues::append()

What is wrong ?

Comment: Looks like the PHP client libraries didn't get updated, I'm looking into it and will report back when they're available.

Comment: You're right ! The sheets.php file on my server (v2.0.2) doesn't have the append method on line 137. Awaiting for the update...

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of the PHP client library being out of date.  An updated version (2.0.3) is released now, and you can run `composer update` to retrieve it.

Comment: Just in the nick of time. I seriously needed the append method today, so this update came at the exact right moment. Thanks!