# Append Row with PHP Library

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using the Google PHP Library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and am trying to append data. According to the docs, https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing#append_values, it's possible. The issue is that the main Sheets Service, `Google_Service_Sheets_Resource_SpreadsheetsValues()`, does not have an `append` method, only `update` (and some others that won't help here).

Answer (score 0):

See [Google sheets API 4: How to append to the end of the row with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392194), asking the same question.  The PHP client library is out of date and missing the append method. I'll report back on that other SO thread when it's fixed. Sorry about that!